# Cross-compiling Bazel Docker Rust image on MacOS to Linux: C++ toolchain not found

Tags: c++, docker, rust, bazel, toolchain

I am trying to cross-compile my Bazel Docker Rust image on MacOS to Linux. Unfortunately, I keep getting an error that the C++ toolchain cannot be found.

> While resolving toolchains for target //service1:service1: No matching toolchains found for types @bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type. Maybe --incompatible_use_cc_configure_from_rules_cc has been flipped and there is no default C++ toolchain added in the WORKSPACE file? See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10134 for details and migration instructions.

Unfortunately the ticket mentioned doesn't provide much useful information.

I think I am missing a default C++ toolchain but I can't find an easy way to add this.

Here are the relevant snippets in my project

**WORKSPACE.bazel**

```
rust_repository_set(
    name = "rust_darwin_linux_cross",
    exec_triple = "x86_64-apple-darwin",
    extra_target_triples = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-musleabihf"],
    iso_date = "2021-06-09",
    version = "nightly",
)
```

**service1/BUILD.bazel**

```
platform(
    name = "linux-x86_64",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
)

rust_image(
    name = "image",
    srcs = ["src/main.rs"],
)
```

The command that I run:  `bazel build --platforms //service1:linux-x86_64 //service1:image`

When I run this command with `--toolchain_resolution_debug=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type` I see that

> Type @bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type: target platform //:linux-x86_64: No toolchains found.

I really hope someone can point me in the right direction as this is a quite confusing topic and there are almost no clear guides or examples on this

Comment: I got it working by copying the code from this example: [https://github.com/duarten/rust-bazel-cross](https://github.com/duarten/rust-bazel-cross). I found out about this example through https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust/issues/276

Comment: Then post this as an answer - and self accept it

Comment: Well I was hoping there would be a solution that does not require so much custom code